# How to enable/disable an option in custom ribbon tab (Typescript/Javascript)?

Tags: excel, office-js

Enable/disable an option in custom ribbon tab (Typescript/Javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to do enable/disable a custom ribbon tab. However, Microsoft is working on it and we hope that this functionality will be added to Office JavaScript library in the near future.